# PHP Pear Mail_Mime: How to fix character enconding?

Tags: php, email, pear

I'm trying to send an email with an attachment using PHP Pear Mail_mime as follows:

```
require_once("/../Mail/mime.php"); 

            $mimeparams['text_encoding']="8bit"; 
            $mimeparams['text_charset']="UTF-8"; 
            $mimeparams['html_charset']="UTF-8"; 
            $mimeparams['head_charset']="UTF-8"; 


            $text = 'Segue em anexo o seu relatório mensal';
            $html = '<html><body>Teste envio relatórios são</body></html>';

        $file = "/../files/abc.pdf";
        $crlf = "\n";
        $hdrs = array(
                      'From'    => '<test@example.com>',
                      'Subject' => 'Relatório'
                      );

        $mime = new Mail_mime(array('eol' => $crlf));

        $mime->setTXTBody($text);
        $mime->setHTMLBody($html);
        $mime->addAttachment($file, 'text/plain');

        $body = $mime->get();
        $hdrs = $mime->headers($hdrs);

        $mail =& Mail::factory('mail');
        $mail->send('test2@gmail.com', $hdrs, $body);
```

It is working fine except the character encoding. On the mail subject, I get:

```
RelatÃ³rio
```

Instead of

```
Relatório
```

And in the body, I get:

```
Teste envio relatÃ³rios sÃ£o
```

Instead of:

```
Teste envio relatórios são
```

I tried including:

```
$mimeparams['text_encoding']="8bit"; 
$mimeparams['text_charset']="UTF-8"; 
$mimeparams['html_charset']="UTF-8"; 
$mimeparams['head_charset']="UTF-8";
```

As seen [here](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mime.example.php) but it didn't work.

Comment: One question: if all you want to do is send an email message with an attachment, then why do you send a html based message? This adds unnecessary load and volume and introduces huge security risks for the receiving party. Send simple plain text messages instead: efficient, reliable, secure.

Comment: @arkascha I just need to send a simple message with attachment, I can live without html but if the subject/body have characters like "Relatório" they are going to be messed up.

Comment: Certainly sending non-ascii characters in a plain text email is possible. People have been doing that for the last 40 years now.

Comment: which encoding is your php file in?